# How can I make references to the glossary more explicit to the reader (of a hard copy)?

Tags: glossaries

I have included a glossary as a separate chapter at the end of my thesis. This chapter lists new terms defined by me. To refer to the glossary in other chapters, I used the `\gls` command, which creates a hyperlink between an occurence of a given "term" in the text and its corresponding glossary entrie(s).

This hyperlink clearly signals to the reader of a **soft copy (PDF)** when I'm referring to the glossary.

However, if the reader only has a **hard copy**, there is no clear indication that a given term is defined in the glossary.

My question is: is there a more explicit way of indicating to the reader that I'm referring to the glossary? I'm thinking along the lines of what the `\cite` command does when I refer to a bibliography entry...

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `\glstextformat` command to specify the format of entries printed via `\gls`.  A simple scheme would be to print these entries in a different font, helping to indicate this is a defined term.  A more explicit approach would be to add a phrase pointing the reader to the glossary.  For example,

```
\renewcommand{\glstextformat}[1]{\textit{#1} (see the glossary)}
```

will print the term in italics and such a phrase afterwards.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\renewcommand{\glstextformat}[1]{\textit{#1} (see the glossary)}

\newglossaryentry{test}{name=test,description={A test entry for glossary}}

\begin{document}

We use \gls{test} as an example of this format.  In the plural
\glspl{test} look like this.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many Thanks Andrew for the answer. I will use "see the glossary" approach. :)